# Has anyone successfully used Cocoapods with OSX Server 3.2 and above?

Tags: macos, cocoapods, xcode6, osx-server, xcode-server

I'm writing this question because, as of now, the download links for OSX 10.9.5 are broken. 
This means I cannot install the pre-release version of OS X Server. The new XCode server supports running scripts prior to running an integration.

I need to quickly verify that my assumption that these pre-integration scripts would allow me to run `pod install`, and that the Bot would be able to open and use the workspace created by Cocoapods.

Has anyone had success with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bot pre-build script worked for me:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/pod install
git reset --hard
```

Unfortunately there's other issues with Xcode 6, Mavericks 10.9.5, and Server 3.2 such as randomly failing to run tests on all simulators and crashes when creating or editing bots that the minor win of being able to install pods without resorting to more elaborate solutions on the server amounts to nothing in reality.